# Improving jquery plugin perfomance

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu

Im writting a plugin to replace the original  with another made by me with html/css, in a few words, a selectbox.

I have problems of perfomance and I acknowledge my code it's fairly heavy.
At first, I take the ID of each select and I add after an HTML code with some css params of the  as width, position...

```
$(this).after("<div class="selectbox" s-id='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'> the code of the select </div>");
```

Then I hide the select, and here comes the part I think is quite heavy, I take all options of this  and I do this

```
var selectbox=$("div[s-id="+selectID+"]"); //This is the div previously added after.

//each option of the select will be converted into a div
$.each($(this).find("option"), function(i) {
    var valor = $(this).val(),
        texto = $(this).text();

    if (i == 0) 
        selectbox.find(".class_valor").text(texto);//The first option to be shown

    //Then I add a li to my drop
    selectbox.find("ul").append('<li  data-value="'+valor+'">'+texto+'</li>');
});
```

And well, now, I don't know if this is the best way to add events to the trigger that opens the dropdown and the click to an option, this is not inside the selectbox function, it's outside inside the `(function($){`

Here is the code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kcpxl

Comment: I'm thinking this may be better served by [the code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe, but I also write it here because I'm also asking which is the best method to do events in plugins etc, so it isn't just a review

Comment: first you should minified your js plugin i think

Comment: @Ispuk I have already done it, I just give you the unminified version ;)

Comment: @SergiFromTheMovies great ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small and easy improvements, cache $(this) and minimize DOM manipulation

```
var selectbox=$("div[s-id="+selectID+"]"); //This is the div previously added after.

    //each option of the select will be converted into a div
    $.each($(this).find("option"), function(i) {
        var $this = $(this), 
            valor = $this.val(),
            texto = $this.text(), 
            liElems = '';

        if (i == 0) 
            selectbox.find(".class_valor").text(texto);//The first option to be shown

        //Then I add a li to my drop
        liElems += '<li  data-value="'+valor+'">'+texto+'</li>';
    });

    selectbox.find("ul").append(liElems);
```

Comment: that is very fine, thanks! and what about the events?